# Application not getting installed on emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

Tags: android, emulation, uploading

I created a 'hello' project. I didn't change anything about the default template generated by eclipse. Then I ran the application. I didn't get any error. However, the application isn't being installed on the emulator.

environment :

```
windows7 x64
jdk-7u7-windows-x64
installer_r20.0.3-windows
eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64
```

I googled many articles, but I didn't find any solutions.

```
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - hello] Android Launch!
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - hello] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - hello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AndroidAVD4.1.2'
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AndroidAVD4.1.2'
[2012-10-15 16:39:42 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Comment: windows7 is 32 or 64 bit ?? problem of version here , I think .

Comment: have you tried creating a emulator with the android avd and then picking it under run config? it seems like the problem could be the emulator that is automatically picked

Answer (score -1):

I have read many similar article for 1 week, and I've tried
many things to fix this problem :

- various android sdk version re-install
- project re-creation
- avd re-creation
- change eclipse workspace
- Changing android sdk folder to root with no space.
- the re-start adb and eclipse.

As a trial, I uninstalled all anti-virus and defense software, then performed a reboot.
This solved my problem.